# What is this $L^p$ inequality in Ambrosio-Gigli-Savaré's book?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

A quick question --- thanks a lot in advance for your help!

I can't understand why the second inequality in (8.3.10) in the Ambrosio-Gigli-Savaré book is true. Here I copy it:

[image: Screenshot from the Ambrosio-Gigli-Savaré book, page 184.]

It seems that they use a relation between the $L^1$ and $L^p$ norm, namely, $\||\mu'|\|_1\leq\||\mu'|\|_p$ with $p\geq 1$. My impression is that the opposite relation is true in general: $\|\cdot\|_a\leq \|\cdot\|_b$ for $1\leq b\leq a$.

Can you maybe remind me of what I might be missing?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just Hölder's inequality: Let $f(s)=\lvert\mu^\prime\rvert(s)$, $g(s)=\left(\int_X\lvert \nabla \phi(x,s)\rvert^q\,d\mu_s(x)\right)^{1/q}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int_J f(s)g(s)\,ds&\leq \left(\int_J f(s)^p\,ds\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_Jg(s)^q\,ds\right)^{1/q}\\
&=\left(\int_J \lvert\mu^\prime\rvert^p(s)\,ds\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_J \int_X\lvert \nabla \phi(x,s)\rvert^q\,d\mu_s(x)\,ds\right)^{1/q}.
\end{align*}